# Understanding compiler optimisations for compile time logic

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

If we have a program which specifies certain *fixed* conditions at compile time, does the compiler determine and fix which 'branch' of the decision tree the program will always run in?

For example, if the following program is compiled with the `-Ofast` flag, does the program spend any time at all actually checking the `if (aFixedCondition)` loop?

```
int main() {
    bool aFixedCondition = true;
    if (aFixedCondition)
        Run_A();
    else
        Run_B();
}
```

Does this also extend to the case in which we do a large number of repeated checks of a fixed condition that is unchanging in our programs lifetime. Something like:

```
int main() {
    bool aFixedCondition = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        if (aFixedCondition)
            Run_A();
        else
            Run_B();
    }
}
```

According to this [post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/359027/is-it-bad-practice-to-write-code-that-relies-on-compiler-optimizations), it is not a 'bad thing' per se to rely on compiler optimisations. Personally I'd rather not do this, but it is unclear how to re-organise the structure of the above program when it is embedded in a more realistic/complicated code. I also could not find anything relevant about the `Ofast` flag ([here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)) in relation to the above.

Comment: The only one to answer your question would be your C++ compiler. And your compiler's answer will likely depend on compilation flags. The only way for you to get an authorative answer that's correct is to inspect your compiler's output.

Comment: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dMGqn6jEn

Comment: Compile the code and have a look at what is generated.

Comment: Right. The output from godbolt is quite nice, in comparison to `g++ -S main.cpp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you show, every good compiler will recognize the `if` condition is true and the `Run_B();` code is unreachable if optimization is enabled. It will then remove the evaluation of `aFixedCondition` and the `Run_B();` code from the program, as well as the `bool aFixedCondition = true;`.

The conditions you show are of course simplistic. It is possible there are controlling expressions in `if` statements or loops that are always true (or always false) but that the compiler cannot recognize this due to various complications in the program. The state of the art is such that if we can easily see that a condition is always true in some direct line of logic, the compiler should be able to as well, and so we might rely on compiler optimizations in such cases. However, if the expression is not easily seen to be always true (or always false), the optimization is more subject to compiler quality and the particular circumstances of the program.

It is not unusual to use this in testing conditions that are compile-time constants but cannot be done with preprocessor tests. For example, in:

```
if (sizeof x == 4)
    DoCodeA();
else
    DoCodeB();
```

we would expect the compiler to know the size of `x` (neglecting the possibility it has some run-time variable size, as do C’s variable length arrays) and remove the unselected code from the program.